# Material ui export 'useInsertionEffect' (imported as 'useInsertionEffect$1') was not found in 'react' using Appbar component

Tags: javascript, material-ui

[image: here is the error.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twJwh.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Zdo.png**strong text**[image]

here i am trying to use Appbar component of material ui but i get this error

Comment: I have the same error with chakraui

Comment: you might need to install a lower version `npm install @mui/material@5.4.2 @emotion/react@11.7.1 @emotion/styled@11.6.0`

Answer (score 10):

This was a bug that [was caused by](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2649) `useInsertionEffect` being [referenced directly](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/pull/2651) in the specifiers list of the import statement (`React.useInsertionEffect` instead of `React['useInsertion' + 'Effect']`).

It [is fixed](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/pull/2652) as of `@emotion/react@11.8.1` - upgrade to that version, and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 9):

npm install @mui/material@5.4.2 @emotion/react@11.7.1 @emotion/styled@11.6.0
solves everything...

Comment: Yes I needed to do all 3 of these to fix the error. Downgrading only @emotion/react was insufficient for me.

Answer (score 7):

I got a similar error, but not with Appbar. I was trying to create my own **npm component library** with mui v5 components.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/comp-lib-mui5-sample/dist/esm/index.js
> 1293:9-29
>
> export 'useInsertionEffect' (imported as 'e') was not found in 'react'
> (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler,
> PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense,
> __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef,
> isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue,
> useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer,
> useRef, useState, version)

Downgrading or upgrading material and emotion, styled did not work.

In my rollup.config.js I had:

```
{
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: "cjs",
            sourcemap: true,
        },
        {
           file: pkg.module,
           format: "esm",
           sourcemap: true,
         },
    ],
    plugins: [ //plugins here ],
},
{
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm"}],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.css$/],
},
```

esm - esm output is used for building for `<script type=module>` tag in modern browsers.
cjs – CommonJS, suitable for Node and other bundlers [rollup output formats](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputformat)

### Fix

New rollup.config.ts that uses only cjs:

```
{
   ...
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: "cjs",
            sourcemap: true,
        },
        // REMOVED esm from here
    ],
    plugins: [ //plugins here ],
},
{
    input: "dist/types/index.d.ts", // CHANGED <--dist/esm/types/library.d.ts
    output: [{file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm"}],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.css$/],
},
```

(works with "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
"@mui/material": "^5.5.2")

Sample repositories: 
component library [Git repo](https://github.com/ViduraAdikari/comp-lib-mui5-sample/tree/feature/mui-rollup-sample) 
consumer of the library [Git repo](https://github.com/ViduraAdikari/consumer-comp-lib-mui5-sample/tree/feature/usage-comp-lib-mui5-sample) 
(check README.md for more info.)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that there is an error in the latest version of `@emotion/react`, `11.8.0`. It was released 3h ago which would explain why it stopped working all of a sudden.

As a workaround, install the older version `@emotion/react@11.7.1` to fix the problems.

Comment: Seems like this newest version is already adapted for react 18. Guess they made a mistake and not tested it with the old version...

Answer (score 1):

This issue for other components in mui lib too, you can downgrade `emotion/react` to [11.7.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/react/v/11.7.1) till it's fixed

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that my component library, built on top of @mui was using react 18, while the consuming application was using v17. Using an older version of @emotion/react and @emotion/styled like `@Savchyk Vladyslav` suggested was fixing the issue, but looking through Github issue of @emotion I couldn't find a single report about this particular error which led me to believe the issue was most likely on my end.

**Downgrading my library's react version to v17, and updating @emotion/react@11.11.1 and @emotion/styled@11.11.0 fixed the issue** and now I'm on the latest and greatest :)

Answer (score -1):

Same happen for me! Downgrading to 11.7.1 fixed!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).