# Attempted import error: 'useInsertionEffect' is not exported from 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-ec2, react-hooks, emotion

Everything was working fine in my react app but today after pushing my latest code, I got the below-mentioned error while Github actions were running build to be pushed on ec2.

The error I am facing on running build:

[image: The error I am facing on running build]

```
Attempted import error: 'useInsertionEffect' is not exported from 
'react' (imported as 'useInsertionEffect$1').
```

Any idea what can be the issue?

I am not facing this on my local machine. I am using react version `17.0.2` and `@emotion/react 11.7.1`

Comment: I've never heard of `useInsertionEffect`, but from googling, it seems it's new in React 18 - so it's hardly surprising you're facing an error trying to import it from React v17!

Comment: yeah, but thing is i am not importing this anywhere in my code.

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue. Yes this looks like a new issue of React18 which is quite new.

Also I don't think this is exact duplicate of [another question here which is more specific about the error with Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185635/material-ui-export-useinsertioneffect-imported-as-useinsertioneffect1-was)

Comment: So it was an error with `@emotion/react` new update, I solved this by downgrading to `@emotion/react 11.7.1`